# TypeError: save() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self' в Django

Tags: python, django

Пытаюсь сохранить новую запись в базу, выдает ошибку

> save() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'

Что не так?

**models.py**

```
class Plugins(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=150, verbose_name='Название')

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('urls_view_current_plugins', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

**tags.py**

```
def add_plugin_in_db():
    plugin = Plugins
    plugin.title = 'title'
    plugin.save(force_insert=True)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вместо

```
plugin = Plugins
```

примените

```
plugin = Plugins()
```

(в вашей  функции `add_plugin_in_db()`), чтобы вы создали **новый объект** класса `Plugins`.

Без скобок вы просто только создали новое имя для *класса* `Plugin`.

Comment: помогло, спасибо, можете посмотреть этот вопрос? https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1243907/cannot-assign-1-plugins-category-must-be-a-pluginscategory-instance-djan

Comment: и почему когда я вызываю в class, то указываю plugin = Plugins без скобок?