# Cannot assign "1": "Plugins.category" must be a "PluginsCategory" instance. Django и запись связанных данных

Tags: python, django

Пытаюсь сохранить новую запись в базу, и ошибка при записи в ForeignKey

*Cannot assign "1": "Plugins.category" must be a "PluginsCategory" instance.*

Что не так?

**models.py**

```
class Plugins(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=150, verbose_name='Название')
    category = models.ForeignKey('PluginsCategory', on_delete=models.PROTECT, related_name='get_category')

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('urls_view_current_plugins', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title


class PluginsCategory(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=150, db_index=True, verbose_name='Наименования категории')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

**tags.py**

```
def add_plugin_in_db():
    plugin = Plugins()
    plugin.title = 'title'
    plugin.category = 1
    plugin.save(force_insert=True)
```

**На сайте**

```
C:\PythonProject\ServiceCRM3\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\related_descriptors.py, line 215, in __set__
            raise ValueError( …
▼ Local vars
Variable    Value
instance    
<Plugins: Заказы>
self    
<django.db.models.fields.related_descriptors.ForwardManyToOneDescriptor object at 0x000000000438DAF0>
value   
1
```

Answer (score 0):

нашел ответ

надо добавлять к переменной связанной ForeignKey поле _id

```
def add_plugin_in_db():
    plugin = Plugins()
    plugin.title = 'title'
    plugin.category_id = 1
    plugin.save(force_insert=True)
```